# Extending class with Mixin declaration

Tags: dart

consider following code:

```dart
class BookStore1 = _BookStoreBase with BookStoreMixin;

class BookStore2 extends _BookStoreBase with BookStoreMixin {}

abstract class _BookStoreBase {}

mixin BookStoreMixin {}
```

I would like to know if declaration of BookStore1 is still appropriate. Issue with it is that I can no longer find it in documentation. It also causes lint warning over _BookStoreBase, saying "Avoid using private types in public APIs": https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/library_private_types_in_public_api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the `BookStore1` class declaration, and you should not be getting any warnings from it, at least not any that you don't also get from `BookStore2`.

Seems like a bug in the lint.

Comment: Thanks for reporting: https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/3668